# How to upload a JSONL file to BigQuery with each row that specifies _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: google-bigquery

I have event data that's being streamed into a BigQuery table that is partitioned by ingestion time, which nearly equals the event timestamp. I can't partition by event timestamp, because certain events don't have it, so we use ingestion time as a compromise.

I have about 200GB of older event data as a JSONL file from the previous 12 months that I'm trying upload.

I've tried having all the JSON rows to include _PARTITIONTIME but get an error for the reserved keyword.

```
const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    schema: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'mail', type: 'JSON'},
            {name: 'delivery', type: 'JSON'},
            {name: '_PARTITIONTIME', type: 'TIMESTAMP'},
        ],
    },
    location: 'US',
};
```

I've tried relabeling _PARTITIONTIME to partitionTimestamp on each JSON row, but it flags an error of it not being part of the schema.

```
const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    schema: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'mail', type: 'JSON'},
            {name: 'delivery', type: 'JSON'},
            {name: 'partitionTimestamp', type: 'TIMESTAMP'},
        ],
        timePartitioning: {
            field: 'partitionTimestamp',
        },
    
    },
    location: 'US',
};
```

[Loading JSON data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_json_data) does not mention uploading to ingestion time tables unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit**

This is the schema for above

```
  schema: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'mail', type: 'JSON'},
            {name: 'delivery', type: 'JSON'},] }
```

***EDIT 2***
With this example JSON, the delivery.timestamp ~= ingestion time, so would like to write this record to the correct day partition.

```
{
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2016-10-19T23:20:52.240Z",
    "source": "sender@example.com",
    "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456789012:identity/sender@example.com",
    "sendingAccountId": "123456789012",
    "messageId": "EXAMPLE7c191be45-e9aedb9a-02f9-4d12-a87d-dd0099a07f8a-000000",
    "destination": [
      "recipient@example.com"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "sender@example.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "To",
        "value": "recipient@example.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "Message sent from Amazon SES"
      },
      {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "7bit"
      }
    ],
    "commonHeaders": {
      "from": [
        "sender@example.com"
      ],
      "to": [
        "recipient@example.com"
      ],
      "messageId": "EXAMPLE7c191be45-e9aedb9a-02f9-4d12-a87d-dd0099a07f8a-000000",
      "subject": "Message sent from Amazon SES"
    },
    "tags": {
      "ses:configuration-set": [
        "ConfigSet"
      ],
      "ses:source-ip": [
        "192.0.2.0"
      ],
      "ses:from-domain": [
        "example.com"
      ],
      "ses:caller-identity": [
        "ses_user"
      ],
      "ses:outgoing-ip": [
        "192.0.2.0"
      ],
      "myCustomTag1": [
        "myCustomTagValue1"
      ],
      "myCustomTag2": [
        "myCustomTagValue2"
      ]      
    }
  },
  "delivery": {
    "timestamp": "2016-10-19T23:21:04.133Z",
    "processingTimeMillis": 11893,
    "recipients": [
      "recipient@example.com"
    ],
    "smtpResponse": "250 2.6.0 Message received",
    "reportingMTA": "mta.example.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the schema of your BigQuery table please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun is this what you were thinking?

Comment: I am going to test it now, please may you add an example of JSON line please ?
I was expecting that the types of `mail` and `delivery` columns are `string`

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is stuck here, here's how I solved it:

1. Stream the files into a corresponding jsonl.gzip file that matches their ingestion date.
2. Load job into BQ. The format is `project.dataset.table#YYMMDD` for that day's partition.

I used S3 to store a backup of all these files, which I don't recommend as they tend to give errors when you go over 5K/second GET requests.